# In SQL how to get the duration within 2 dates subtracting a timeframe whenever it occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the duration between 2 datetimes excluding breaks. I calculate total time using for example if t1 is '02/12/2018 14:18:29' and t2 is '02/14/2018 14:18:29'

```
select datediff(second,t1,t2)
```

Now if I want to exclude the time there were breaks like if  14:30 to 14:45 was a break every day, how do I create my query.

I tried

```
select 
    datediff(minute, t1, t2) -
    (select 
         case
            when cast(t1 as time) > '14:30:00:000' and cast(t2 as time) < '14:45:00:000'  
               then 15 
               else 0 
         end as breaks)
```

But I don't seem to get the right answer

Comment: do all records get that 15 minute break?

Comment: Your < and > signs are reversed.

Comment: Which dbms???????  Date functions are very vendor specific.

Comment: Can you please add a tag for the SQL dialect you're using? E.g. MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: It is sql Server

Comment: if t1 and t2 cover only one day then subtracting only one break will work, but if t1 to t2 cover more than one day how to subtract that many breaks